# ¿How do I manage the Firebase: Error (auth/argument-error) in an Angular app?

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

Been trying to implement a Google Account Login on an Angular App but keep getting this error everytime I summon the function which contains the GoogleAuthProvider. This is how my component service looks like:

```
import * as auth from 'firebase/auth';
import { ObjetoLogin } from './SignUp';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import {
  AngularFirestore,
  AngularFirestoreDocument,
} from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthenticationService {
  userData: any;

  constructor(
    public afStore: AngularFirestore,
    public ngFireAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    public router: Router,
    public ngZone: NgZone
  ) {
    this.ngFireAuth.authState.subscribe((user) => {
      if (user) {
        this.userData = user;
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.userData));
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user') || '{}');
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem('user', null || '{}');
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user') || '{}');
      }
    });
  }

//Other code...

  //Iniciar sesión - Gmail
  GoogleAuth() {
    const provider = new auth.GoogleAuthProvider
    return this.AuthLogin(provider);
  }
  
  // Proveedores para Autenticación
  AuthLogin(provider: any) {
    return this.ngFireAuth
      .signInWithPopup(provider)
      .then((result) => {
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
          this.router.navigate(['home']);
        });
        this.userData(result.user);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error Code: ', error.code);
        console.log('Error Message: ', error.message)
        window.alert(error);
      });
  }

  //Other code...

}
```

```
My Firebase Config which is exported into the app.module:
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  firebaseConfig: {
    apiKey: **********************,
    authDomain: **********************,
    databaseURL: **********************,
    projectId: **********************,
    storageBucket: **********************,
    messagingSenderId: **********************,
    appId: **********************
  }
};
```

And my app.module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';

import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire/compat';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import { AngularFireStorageModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/storage';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/database';

import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DatesViewComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    IonicComponentsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    //Importaciones para el uso de Firebase
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    AngularFireStorageModule,
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Already tried changing the way I pass the GoogleAuthProvider as:

```
  GoogleAuth() {
    return this.AuthLogin(new auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
  }
```

But still doesn't seems to work while I keep getting the error:

```
FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/argument-error).
    at createErrorInternal (VM3284 vendor.js:1653:37)
    at _fail (VM3284 vendor.js:1622:9)
    at _assertInstanceOf (VM3284 vendor.js:1640:7)
    at Module.<anonymous> (VM3284 vendor.js:10789:5)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (VM3284 vendor.js:177695:24)
    at _next (VM3284 vendor.js:177714:9)
    at VM3284 vendor.js:177719:7
    at new ZoneAwarePromise (VM3283 polyfills.js:9305:21)
    at Module.<anonymous> (VM3284 vendor.js:177711:12)
```